# Question on probability rolling 2 dice

Tags: probability, dice

Let's say I roll a $6$-sided die and a $10$-sided die. Now, if I am going to pay the sum of the two rolls, how much will I pay on average?

> The average sum of a single $6$-sided die would be $3.5$ --> $\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6}$

> The average sum of a single $10$-sided die would be $5.5$ --> $\frac{10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1}{10}$

So am I correct if I say that on average I would pay $4.5$ --> $\frac{5.5+3.5}{2}$ ?

Comment: No. Since you are paying the sum you expect to pay the sum of the expectations, namely $3.5+5.5=9$.   There is no reason to divide by $2$.

Comment: Your answer would be correct **if** you were paying the average of the two rolls, not the sum.

Comment: okay it was a bit confusing because the question is asking 'how much will I pay on average'... that's why I divided by 2, thanks for the clarification